# Reasons for "No matching function for call [func name]" in C++

Tags: c++, function

I know this question has been asked here many times, but still none of them match my case. I really don't know what could be causing this. I posted the full code below, as I am not sure where the error is, so I couldn't make snippets.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>
#include <map>

struct edge{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    edge(int p1, int p2){
        n1 = p1;
        n2 = p2;
    }
};

void make_connected(int i, int degrees[], bool (&connected)[], std::forward_list<int> (&connections)[], std::forward_list<int> &not_full, int k);

void find_not_full_neighbour(int &not_full_neighbour, std::forward_list<int> connections, int degrees[], bool connected[], int k);

int main(){
    int n; //#nodes
    int k; //max #edges per node
    int p; //#edges

    std::cin >> n >> k >> p;

    int degrees[n]; //#edges per node

    std::forward_list<int> connections[n];

    bool connected[n];
    std::fill(connected, connected + n, false);

    std::forward_list<int> not_full; //Nodes I can connect more edges to

    int to_add_count = 0;
    std::forward_list<edge> to_add; //Solution

    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){ //Add edges from input
        int n1;
        int n2;
        std::cin >> n1 >> n2;
        if(n1 != n2){
            connections[n1].push_front(n2);
            connections[n2].push_front(n1);
        }
        degrees[n1] ++;
        degrees[n2] ++;
        not_full.push_front(n1);
        not_full.push_front(n2);
    }

    if(not_full.empty()){ //If there are no nodes with less than k edges
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(degrees[i] < k){ //If can connect more edges
                degrees[i]++; //Increase the degree

                not_full.push_front(i); //Add this node to the list

                make_connected(i, degrees, connected, connections, not_full, k); //ERROR HERE
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(connected[i]){ //If already connected skip
            continue;
        }

        if(degrees[i] < k){ //If can connect more edges
            if(!not_full.empty() && degrees[not_full.front()] < k){ //If can connect to first node in list
                degrees[i]++; //Increase the degree
                degrees[not_full.front()]++; //Increase the degree of the node in the list

                to_add_count++;
                to_add.push_front(edge(i, not_full.front())); //Add to the solution

                connections[i].push_front(not_full.front()); //Add to the connections list

                not_full.push_front(i); //Add this node to the list

                make_connected(i, degrees, connected, connections, not_full, k); //ERROR HERE
            }
            else if(degrees[not_full.front()] >= k){ //If can't connect to first node in list
                not_full.pop_front(); //Pop and run again
                i--; 
            }else if(not_full.empty()){ //If list is empty
                std::cout << -1 << std::endl; //No solution
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else{ //If can't connect more edges
            int not_full_neighbour = -1;
            find_not_full_neighbour(not_full_neighbour, connections[i], degrees, connected, k); //Find a not full neighbour
            if(not_full_neighbour == -1){
                std::cout << -1 << std::endl; //No solution
                return 0;
            }
            else{ //If there is a not full/connected neighbour
                degrees[not_full_neighbour]++; //Increase the degree
                degrees[not_full.front()]++; //Increase the degree of the node in the list

                to_add_count++;
                to_add.push_front(edge(not_full_neighbour, not_full.front())); //Add to the solution

                connections[not_full_neighbour].push_front(not_full.front()); //Add to the connections list

                not_full.push_front(not_full_neighbour); //Add this node to the list

                make_connected(i, degrees, connected, connections, not_full, k); //ERROR HERE
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << to_add_count << std::endl;
    for(edge e : to_add){
        std::cout << e.n1 << " " << e.n2 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void make_connected(int i, int degrees[], bool (&connected)[], std::forward_list<int> (&connections)[], std::forward_list<int> &not_full, int k){
    connected[i] = true;
    if(degrees[i] < k){
        not_full.push_front(i);
    }
    for(int n : connections[i]){
        make_connected(n, degrees, connected, connections, not_full, k);
    }
}

void find_not_full_neighbour(int &not_full_neighbour, std::forward_list<int> connections, int degrees[], bool connected[], int k){
    for(int n : connections){
        if(degrees[n] < k && connected[n]){ //If found
            not_full_neighbour = n; //Set and return
            return;
        }
        else{ //If not found
            find_not_full_neighbour(not_full_neighbour, connections, degrees, connected, k); //Run on this node
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get errors on all the cases in the `main` function where I call `make_connected` (commented):

> No matching function for call make_connected

I am quite sure I am calling the function with the right parameters, and there shouldn't be anything else called the same. I think the problem might be in the way in which I pass arrays to the function, as I am quite new to C++ and don't really know how to do it correctly.

Comment: `int n;` `int degrees[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time value, not a runtime value.  This should be `std::vector<int> degrees(n);`.  It is the same issue with `std::forward_list<int> connections[n];` and `bool connected[n];`.  Those should be `std::vector<std::forward_list<int>> connections(n);` and `std::vector<bool> connected(n);`

Comment: [See the errors mentioned](https://godbolt.org/z/4vGWcerYn).

Comment: *I am quite sure I am calling the function with the right parameters...* (but you are not) *...I am quite new to C++ and don't really know how to do it correctly*  That being the case, why are you quite sure you are calling the function with the right parameters?

Comment: @Eljay I just wanted to indicate that I have already checked that and actually done some research beforehand and believe that I am in fact passing the right parameters. Of course I am most definitely open to suggestions on how to solve this problem. Which of the parameters is wrong?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Great thanks a lot that solved it. Could you write it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: If you change non-C++ (C-style VLA) `int degrees[n]` to C++ `std::vector<int> degrees(n);`, then you could pass that variable to a function `void x(std::vector<int>& d);` or `void x(std::vector<int> const& d);` using `x(degrees);` at the callsite.